# Flash CS4 dynamic text in arabic issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, fonts, flash-cs4

n Flash CS4 IDE i try to put in Text Field with dynamic type some string in arabic and to stylize it with embedded Arial font. The problem is that i see the text , but it is "reversed" and for this reason some letters not connected as it have to be in arabic . How can i solve it? In "Character embedding" list i chose arabic, it doesn't helped.
I use ActionScript 3. For some reasons i have to use Flash CS4 . I know that in Flash CS5 and above there is some  textlayout component with international languages and RTL support
Thanks a lot and good day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this will fix your problem but try setting the textfield font to _sans

This uses the PC's own default _sans font.

Comment: Thank you for the advice , but i need it to be fith embedded Arial, because this text field must support some special characters and hebrew too